# Restoring from a completely different farm backup

Tags: 2010, backup, restore, farm

I'm sure this will sound like a very novice question and many will wonder the application of such an action, but here goes.

Say I have two different single-server SharePoint instances (2 different servers each with their own databases). If I did a farm backup on Server A, could I then go into Server B > Central Admin > Restore from Backup > select Server A's farm backup, and now Server B's SharePoint looks exactly like Server A?

Comment: Will both farms be hosted within the same ActiveDirectory Domain?

Comment: I'm glad you brought that to my attention. I believe so. We just got bought by another company so while they work on merging the AD's we still have ours going with a 1 way trust from theirs to ours (we trust them wholly, but they don't trust us)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be answered with yes or no. There are many things to consider:

- Target farm's patchlevel needs to be equal or greater than source farm.
- Does the new farm have the same license? If you are on enterprise and target farm is standard you wont be able to use the database.
- Does the new farm have all ServiceApplications installed?
- You cannot merge every ServiceApplication without 3rd party tools (like ManagedMetaData Service)
- You need to apply all customizations, configuration and farm-solutions to the new farm. Maybe you need to move a license or even upgrade a license if the target farm has more servers than the source farm
- [Configure PeoplePicker to resolve people from the 1way trusted domain](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server-2010/gg602075(v=office.14)#enable-cross-forest-or-cross-domain-queries-when-using-a-one-way-trust)

Comment: It sounds like it is a Yes/No answer though. All those things you just mentioned pretty much point to the fact that if target farm is not a darn near mirror of source farm then it can't happen. Which answers my question. I just wasn't sure if you could "hot swap" databases as long as they lined up together and the front end just displays the swapped stuff. Thank you

Comment: If you aren't customized at all and do not rely on ServiceApplications, you might be able to do a simple move. For example if SharePoint was used as a simple FileShare. Just make sure, PeoplePicker works as expected, but thats one line of STSADM.